# Getting value from Fragment into mainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity. It's layout contains a fragmentContainer and an actionBar. Then I have 2 different fragments containing various EditTexts.All of them have Ids. I populate the fragmentContainer with the fragments when user clicks a button in actionBar. Everything works perfectly.

Now...the app, is supposed to collect the contents of all EditTexts from both fragments when I push a button (in the menu of the actionBar). But it does not work. It crashes when I try to access the EditTexts directly from the activity. I understand that I should create a public method inside the code of the fragments that will return the values I am interested in. But I seem to be doing something wrong because the method is not accessible from the main (TabActivity)

Here is my code:

```
public class TabActivity extends Activity {
    ActionBar.Tab tab_alocare, tab_merc;
    Fragment fragmentTab1 = new aloc_fragment();
    Fragment fragmentTab2 = new merc_fragment();

    @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab); // this layout contains the fragmentContainer
        ...// here I do some actionBar stuff
        }
...
}
```

An example of one of the fragments is bellow:

```
public class aloc_fragment extends Fragment {
    EditText mEditText;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aloc, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.edaloc);
    }
    public String getMyText() {
        String rez = "";
        if (mEditText.getText()!=null) {
            rez = mEditText.getText().toString();
        }
        return rez;
    }
}
```

Now... if inside the Activity code I want to access the edaloc EditText using findViewById, it crashes the app with nullException. So I then tried to access the public method of the fragment so that it would return me the value that I need. But "getMyText" method is not accessible from the TabActivity.

So, this code does not work:

```
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.save:
          Fragment alocfragment = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("aloc");
          String s = alocfragment.getMyText(); // this is not compiling at all
```

I am clearly doing something wrong.
Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: mEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.edaloc); you have added this in onActivityCreated . so when you invoke getMyText() mEditText reference is not available since it will be created only when the fragment is created

Comment: I changed that. I added it to the onCreateView. Still no change

Comment: onCreateView() will be invoked only when the fragment is created. In your onOptionsSelected() you are just getting the reference and not creating the fragment !!. Create a text change listener for EditText "mEditText". This listener will be triggered when the edittext has lost its focus meaning the user has finished entering the text. Then   in your getMyText() method jus return the value of "rez" whose contents will be fetched within the text change listener of mEditText

Comment: Thanks, using a TextChangeListener and GlobalVariables I can do what I need. I am not too certain that it is a good approach, but it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of mistakes in your code, You have neither `declared` nor `initialize` the fragments at proper place. Also, you are trying to `create` another instance of fragment in `onOptionsItemSelected` which is wrong, you need to use same instance of fragment there to access your functions with values. I hope you know how to add and inflate fragment. See my comments and code changes.

Try with this -

```
public class TabActivity extends Activity {
    ActionBar.Tab tab_alocare, tab_merc;
    //Declare fragments here
    Fragment fragmentTab1;
    Fragment fragmentTab2;

    @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab); // this layout contains the fragmentContainer

        //Initialize here
         fragmentTab1 = new aloc_fragment();
         fragmentTab2 = new merc_fragment();
        //inflate/add fragments here to the activity


        ...// here do your actionBar stuff
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.save:
        //Now, use same instance of fragment to access your function
        String s = fragmentTab1.getMyText();
    }
}

public class aloc_fragment extends Fragment {
    EditText mEditText;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aloc,
        container, false);
        //hold edittext here in the variable
        mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edaloc);
        return view;
    }
    public String getMyText() {
        String rez = "";
        if (mEditText.getText()!=null) {
            rez = mEditText.getText().toString();
        }
        return rez;
    }
}
```

> Also, must to go through Fragment tutorial on [Android Developer Fragment Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) [Link 2](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), [Using Fragments](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#usingfragments_)

Comment: Still the method getMyText is not accessible from the TabActivity

Comment: Even if I follow your code, the inner method getMyText is not accessible from the activity. It does not appear to be broken my way either, since everything else works just fine. All links of tutorials that you gave me (read them a long time ago btw) describe how to send stuff to the fragments, and none of them describe methods to get stuff from the fragment. I really thought that because it is not described in the official docs, then it probably is something easy as pie and not worth mentioning in the docs.

Comment: Please try it yourself with a blank project. You can even get a working example of what I try to implement here ( http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture08/lecture08.html ). It is exactly what I am doing, except there is no reference here either about getting stuff from fragments. But you can use this as a starting point and try to get values from fragments yourself. Just place an EditText in each fragment that you have in the project, and try to get their values in the menu click.

Comment: The only solution that I see so far, is for me to use GlobalVariable class, and set values from within the fragment class on an event like onTextChange listener. Since I haven't seen anybody else suggesting this solution anywhere on the web, I am inclined to believe that it it probably a bad idea... But I do not know that for sure. And also I don't have any other working solution. _So if you have a better solution , please advise_.